# Looping: i vs loopCount

Tags: java, loops, naming-conventions

Is it better to use the variable 'i' or a meaningful name such as 'loopCount' or 'studentsCount' etc?

e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        System.out.println(i + j);
    } // End of j loop
} // End of i loop
```

**VS**

```
for (int outerLoop = 0; outerLoop < 10; outerLoop++)
{
    for (int innerLoop = 0; innerLoop < 5; innerLoop++)
    {
        System.out.println(outerLoop + innerLoop);
    } // End of innerLoop
} // End of outerLoop
```

By *better*; the main considerations would be readability / conventions.

Related question [Loop iterator naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914581/loop-iterator-naming-convention)

**EDIT:**
I have tagged this a java, but answers for other languages are welcome.

Comment: Preference really. Everyone knows i, though it can make for ugly confusing code.

Comment: You should use int instead of Integer.

Comment: I personally prefer 'i' for very simple loops such as the ones in the examples, but definitely prefer meaningful names in more complex situations.

Comment: `i` and `j` is just like in math,

Comment: Use longer names if the meaning of the index isn't obvious, such as if your lopp is very long (though in this case consider breaking it up) or you have a lot of nesting. Otherwise, using wordy names that doesn't add clarity to the code just wastes space and attention.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, using Integer here is very expensive because Integer is immutable. Thus each time you do an increment it unboxes the previous Integer, do an increment and creates another Integer to hold the new value. You need to use int.

Secondly, whether to have a readable name really up to the semantics of the int. If it's just a control variable over a pre-determined number of loops I think i is fine; but if it has specific meaning then you are free to give it a better meaningful name.

Answer (score 6):

Code is communication: what do you want the reader of this code (who might be you months or years from now) to think when he sees it?  To me, using "i" and "j" in a loop says "do this thing 10 times; the variable is just a convention and means nothing", while using a more descriptive variable like "studentID" says "this number actually refers to something specific"  I'd use the former if I want to de-emphasize the variable itself, and the latter if I want to highlight it.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen many loops that started out small and grew very large with other loops added inside and around them and it all became a confusing mess of i j k x y z. Name your references with the shortest name that **expresses your intent**, so another dev will know what you were going for.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally i and j are used for this type of thing, but there's certainly nothing wrong with giving them a meaningful name to aid in readability. If I were reading another persons code, I would rather prefer outer/innerloop to i and j.

Answer (score 1):

Use `i` and `j` if you want. People reading your code will probably decode these to be the names of loop variables, and if they can't, then shame on *them*.

> *(( if you use long names for loop variables in a language where long names will hinder performance, then I'll slap you ))*

Answer (score 1):

In the looping you can use i , j (not meaningful name) and the program will compile and run.
But in the big project if you use i, j , this is only know you. Other person who is your leader difficult to understand your code. That why you should make habit even there are not big project.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

i and j origin in mathematical conventions for matrices, as a form of abstraction. I use it mainly in an math/numeric algorithm context.